# Local Notifications Control Time

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have a local notification in my app that goes off exactly 5 days since the app was last used. I have had a review saying that the sound is annoying when it goes off at midnight. Is there anyway that I can prevent the notification from playing if it is between a certain system time? I really want to keep this notification but I don't want the users to become annoyed with it going off at early hours (even if they were the ones who were on at that time 5 days prior)
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why don't you just not schedule it for that time?

Comment: I want it to go off at 5 days after the app was last used but not if it's going to go off between say 10pm-10am. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It's just simple math man.  There are hundreds of questions about how to get various units out of `NSDate` (the class you use to schedule your notification in the first place).  If you calculate that it will go off during that time, then schedule it a bit further ahead or a bit further behind.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to this, so I guess i'll have to look into this further. Thanks anyway